# How to use javascript variables within jQuery's .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My example code right now looks like this:

```
<script>
   var number = 10;
   $('.someclass').html(
       number  
   )
</script>
```

However, in the results, the output is just the number var name, instead of the javascript variable's proper numerical value, 10. Thanks for you help you guys!

UPDATE: This is exactly what I have

```
          $('.well.well-large.' + number).html(
                "."
              article_id
              {{ cur_articles.article_id.title }}
              {{ cur_articles.article_id.domain }}

          ).hide().fadeIn(500);
```

The "." is needed for me so the hide() does not error out. Perhaps thats causing the problem.

UPDATE: As it turns out, "." was causing the issue, after removing it, it's back to normal. Not sure why though.

Comment: you are doing it right. I also tried your piece of code in my browser just to be sure and it works fine

Comment: Are you putting the variable name in quotes eg. `.html("number")` ? That could be the problem.

Comment: I also just checked it to be sure. It works. Make sure `number` is not inside quotation marks.

Comment: No, it's not in quotes, i'll post specifically what I have.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate those strings together? You'll then need to put a plus sign between them: `"." + article_id + {{...}}`

Comment: No i'm not, that is there because if it's not, hide() won't work on occasions, when my variables return as none for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 10;
$('body').html(number)
```

try this in the console of your browser it should give you 10.